# Replay script syntax error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want as I press replay button, all video stream, music stops and and starts from frame one.

Right now problem is that video and music doesn't stop it continues to play but the motion tweens perform the action as they are directed i.e. plays from frame 1.

Code which I'm using is

```
stop();

replay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,fReplay,false,0,true);
function fReplay(e:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

Note: video is in server and it's directly played from there. music is in local library.

Comment: You should reset every stream separately and according to the playing method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `gotoAndPlay(1)`, I suggest you to use this code :

```
stop();

replay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,fReplay,false,0,true);
function fReplay(e:MouseEvent):void{
   replay.prevFrame();
}
```

It will allow to go all the way back to the first frame.
Or if you want to trigger a Frame, well put the number in the ().

And you will be done.

Kind regards